# Is there any way to stop a pickle process prematurely?

Tags: python, pickle

I have a program where I use `pickle` to save and load fairly large and complex datasets, which can take up to 30s. The process is handled in a secondary thread and comes with a dialog that shows the progress and has a button to cancel it. Now is there actually a way to stop the dumping or saving? My feeling is that as soon as the process is started, it will finish no matter what.

So basically, if you have something like

```
import pickle

data = 1
with open('./file', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(data, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    # or
    data = pickle.load(file)
```

Is there any way to stop the file from being (over)written? Or the data being loaded into memory?

Comment: I've never seen documentation for any such feature.

Comment: If `file` was made accessible somehow outside of the thread, I'm pretty sure that `file.close()` would stop the pickle process fairly quickly.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks! But I think I start to see why so many processes buffer in a temporary file first before saving it as the actual file. This way, if the process is interrupted somehow, the file won't be corrupted. So maybe I should do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ways to do it is to slice your datasets into pieces, and check for cancel at every step, for example:

```
import pickle

cancel = False
dataset_path = './dataset.pkl'

dataset = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

with open(dataset_path, 'wb') as handle:
    for data in dataset:
        if cancel:
            break
        pickle.dump(data, handle, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    # or

dataset = []
with open(dataset_path, 'rb') as handle:
    while 1:
        try:
            dataset.append(pickle.load(handle))
        except EOFError:
            break

print(dataset)
```

Outputs:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why pickle doesn't overwrite the file but instead appends it?

Comment: Because I open the file before the loop and dump the data, if you make `for` loop outside the `with open` statement, then it will overwrite the file and outputs `[[7, 8, 9]]`

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. Thank you! It seems for now, this is the best way to handle it.